# Undo reverse merge in Subversion, or double-reverse merge

Tags: svn, merge, reverse, undo

What is the best way to undo a committed reverse merge?

Here's the scenario: I committed a change, say revision 100, which caused a regression.  Since I was leaving for a few days and didn't have time to debug the issue, I reverse-merged 100 and committed revision 101.  Now I'm ready to attack the issue again.  I have three ideas for doing this, but I don't know what is best or even what will work:

1. Reverse merge revision 101
2. Merge revision 100
3. Copy the changes made in 100 to my working copy without mergeinfo

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse merging revision 101 describes best what you're doing, ie undoing the undo.